# How can I implement a read function with a timeout after sending a frame in the same programm?

Tags: sockets, server, udp, timeout, client

I implemented a communication between a client and server. But I have a problem, after sending a CAN frame with the function can_SendIsoTP() the select function is set to 0 even though it should be 1 because it get to read directly data from the server. Do you know why it doesn't work.

It works only when I am doing a breaking point before the select line is executed or with the sleep function (std::chrono::seconds dura(1); std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);)

```
                FD_ZERO(&fd);
                FD_SET(s, &fd);
                can_SendIsoTP(s, result);
                //std::chrono::seconds dura(1);
                //std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
                rv = select(s + 1, &fd,NULL, NULL, &timeout);
                if (rv == -1)
                    perror("select"); /* an error accured */
                else if (rv == 0)
                    printf("timeout"); /* a timeout occured */
                else
                {
                    nbytes = read(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                }
```

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: How are you setting the `timeout` variable?

Comment: Here are the settings of my timeout value: struct timeval timeout {}; timeout.tv_sec = 0; timeout.tv_usec = 1000000; //ms

Comment: The timeout value should be normalised - try setting `timeout.tv_sec = 1; timeout.tv_usec = 0` instead.  Also, you should set `timeout` just before the `select()` call, because `select()` will update it with the time remaining, so if you re-use `timeout` for multiple calls it might not be what you expect.